# Recibir json en web service rest con jersey

Tags: java, rest, java-ee, jersey

Estoy realizando un web service rest con jersey, y necesito recibir un json como parámetro. El json es complejo, por lo que pensé en recibirlo como String. Aqui estan mis archivos:

```
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.FormParam;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.PUT;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

import mx.unam.utict.remisionescfdi.service.RemisionesService;

@Path("/remisiones")
public class RemisionesServiceImpl implements RemisionesService{
    @Override
    @PUT
    @Path("/actualizar/{json}")
    @Produces("text/plain; charset=UTF-8")
    @Consumes("application/json; charset=UTF-8")
    public String actualizaRemisiones(@PathParam("json") String json) {
        
        /*Gson gson = new Gson();
        Documentos documentos = gson.fromJson(json, Documentos.class);*/
        
        System.out.println(json);
        System.out.println("Entre a actualizar");
        
        return "regresa";
    }

}
```

Este es mi web xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>remisionesCFDI</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>servicesJR</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>mx.unam.utict.remisionescfdi.serviceimpl</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>servicesJR</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Y por ultimo el pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>mx.unam.utict</groupId>
  <artifactId>remisionesCFDI</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <dependencies>
   <!-- Inicio Servlet y JSP-->
    <dependency>
          <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
          <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
          <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
          <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
          <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
          <version>2.1</version>
          <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
          <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
          <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
          <version>1.19.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
          <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
          <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
          <version>1.19.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
          <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
          <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
          <version>1.19.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.6</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

He intentado recibir el json usando las anotaciones `@PathParam`, `@QueryParam` y `@FormParam` pero ninguna me a funcionado. La anotación `@PathParam` si funciona si mando una cadena sencilla como por ejemplo **"prueba"** pero con un json no me funciona. Las otras dos solo me pintan el siguiente warning:

> may 06, 2021 11:15:37 AM
> com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent filterFormParameters
> ADVERTENCIA: A servlet request, to the URI
> http://localhost:8086/remisionesCFDI/services/remisiones/actualizar?json=prueba,
> contains form parameters in the request body but the request body has
> been consumed by the servlet or a servlet filter accessing the request
> parameters. Only resource methods using @FormParam will work as
> expected. Resource methods consuming the request body by other means
> will not work as expected.

Aun así los System.out.println no se pintan. Lo estoy invocando desde soapui de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguien puede indicarme que estoy haciendo mal?

```
   [{ "dependencia":"764",
   "subdep":"02",
   "serie":"HGEACF",
   "ejercicio":"2021",
   "folio_cfd":116119,
   "dependencias":[
      {
         "dep_producto":"321",
         "subdep_producto ":"01",
         "remisiones":[
            {
               "renglon":"1",
               "cantidad":1,
               "cve_producto":"01010101",
               "cve_producto_no_identificado":0,
               "cve_subproducto":0,
               "remision":"36"
            },
            {
               "renglon":"2",
               "cantidad":2,
               "cve_producto":"0000000",
               "cve_producto_no_identificado":0,
               "cve_subproducto":0,
               "remision":"36"
            },
            {
               "renglon":"3",
               "cantidad":6,
               "cve_producto":"01010101",
               "cve_producto_no_identificado":0,
               "cve_subproducto":0,
               "remision":"36"
            },
            {
               "renglon":"4",
               "cantidad":6,
               "cve_producto":"01010101",
               "cve_producto_no_identificado":0,
               "cve_subproducto":0,
               "remision":"38"
            }
         ]
      },
            {
         "dependencia":"417",
         "subdep":"01",
         "remisiones":[
            {
               "renglon":"1",
               "cantidad":1,
               "cve_producto":"01010101",
               "cve_producto_no_identificado":0,
               "cve_subproducto":0,
               "remision":"142"
            },
            {
               "renglon":"2",
               "cantidad":2,
               "cve_producto":"01010101",
               "cve_producto_no_identificado":0,
               "cve_subproducto":0,
               "remision":"661"
            },
            {
               "renglon":"3",
               "cantidad":1,
               "cve_producto":"01010101",
               "cve_producto_no_identificado":0,
               "cve_subproducto":0,
               "remision":"937"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "dependencia":"764",
         "subdep":"02",
         "remisiones":[
            {
               "renglon":"1",
               "cantidad":1,
               "cve_producto":"01010101",
               "cve_producto_no_identificado":0,
               "cve_subproducto":0,
               "remision":"142"
            },
            {
               "renglon":"2",
               "cantidad":2,
               "cve_producto":"01010101",
               "cve_producto_no_identificado":0,
               "cve_subproducto":0,
               "remision":"661"
            },
            {
               "renglon":"3",
               "cantidad":1,
               "cve_producto":"01010101",
               "cve_producto_no_identificado":0,
               "cve_subproducto":0,
               "remision":"937"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
},
{
   "dependencia":"764",
   "subdep":"02",
   "serie":"HGEACF",
   "ejercicio":"2021",
   "folio_cfd":119988,
   "dependencias":[
      {
         "dep_producto":"321",
         "subdep_producto ":"01",
         "remisiones":[
            {
               "renglon":"1",
               "cantidad":1,
               "cve_producto":"01010101",
               "cve_producto_no_identificado":0,
               "cve_subproducto":0,
               "remision":"36"
            },
            {
               "renglon":"2",
               "cantidad":2,
               "cve_producto":"0000000",
               "cve_producto_no_identificado":0,
               "cve_subproducto":0,
               "remision":37
            },
            {
               "renglon":"3",
               "cantidad":6,
               "cve_producto":"01010101",
               "cve_producto_no_identificado":0,
               "cve_subproducto":0,
               "remision":38
            },
            {
               "renglon":"4",
               "cantidad":6,
               "cve_producto":"01010101",
               "cve_producto_no_identificado":0,
               "cve_subproducto":0,
               "remision":38
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "dependencia":"417",
         "subdep":"01",
         "remisiones":[
            {
               "renglon":"1",
               "cantidad":1,
               "cve_producto":"01010101",
               "cve_producto_no_identificado":0,
               "cve_subproducto":0,
               "remision":"142"
            },
            {
               "renglon":"2",
               "cantidad":2,
               "cve_producto":"01010101",
               "cve_producto_no_identificado":0,
               "cve_subproducto":0,
               "remision":"661"
            },
            {
               "renglon":"3",
               "cantidad":1,
               "cve_producto":"01010101",
               "cve_producto_no_identificado":0,
               "cve_subproducto":0,
               "remision":"937"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "dependencia":"764",
         "subdep":"02",
         "remisiones":[
            {
               "renglon":"1",
               "cantidad":1,
               "cve_producto":"01010101",
               "cve_producto_no_identificado":0,
               "cve_subproducto":0,
               "remision":"142"
            },
            {
               "renglon":"2",
               "cantidad":2,
               "cve_producto":"01010101",
               "cve_producto_no_identificado":0,
               "cve_subproducto":0,
               "remision":"661"
            },
            {
               "renglon":"3",
               "cantidad":1,
               "cve_producto":"01010101",
               "cve_producto_no_identificado":0,
               "cve_subproducto":0,
               "remision":"937"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
]
```

Comment: @Produces("text/plain; charset=UTF-8")
 @Consumes("application/json; charset=UTF-8") no entiendo por que no recibes como json y solo devuelves como json, cual es la complejidad?

Comment: El json es lo complejo, no lo recibe, por eso busco recibirlo como string